# How do we do a hypothesis testing for continous X and Y variable

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-test

I have a dataset where I have number of hours I the student has studied v/s Marks scored. The question is to hypothesis test "students who have studied less have scored more"

Answer (score 0):

Best Way I found was to do correlation. Since data was non-parametric I ended up using spearman rho.